# How can I derive from a controller of a second project in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using C# and and mvc3.  I added a project to a solution.  I would like to create a new controller and let it derive from a controller inside the project that I added.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio you can [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx) to the second project. Then import the namespace and there you go.

Answer (score 1):

Move your original controller, or more likely create a controller containing just the functionality that you want to share, to a new class library project as a base controller.  Have both web projects include the library as a reference and let your controllers both derive from the base controller.